# Find the missing 2 number inside inner circle

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

This puzzle is made by me. In the below diagram you can see there are two missing numbers; you need to fill them with the appropriate numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing numbers are

> -13 and 16

Reasoning

> There are 3 types of numbers. Outer, Middle and Inner. The outer number is sum of the middle number on the same side and the inner number on the opposite side.

So

> The outer number 14 is the sum of 27 and **-13**. And 41 is the sum of 25 and **16**

Comment: you are right .. well done :)